# Custom TypeScript extensions for Angular 1.x

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I'm upgrading to TypeScript 2.x from 1.x and running into trouble with custom additions to types, for example with Angular 1.x. I have from DefinitelyTyped/npm:

```
/node_modules/@types/angular/index.d.ts
```

No I want to extend the `IFilterService` definition to define another overload and type my custom filter in `/types/angular/index.d.ts`.

```
/// <reference path="../../node_modules/@types/angular/index.d.ts" />

declare namespace angular {

    interface IFilterService {
        (name: 'shortDate'):(date:Date) => string;
    }
}
```

Then I try to take advantage of the typing like this:

```
function($filter:ng.IFilterService):void {
    const formatFn:(date:Date) => string = $filter('shortDate');
}
```

but no go:

> error TS2322: Type '{}' is not assignable to type '(date: Date) => string'

I do have both `node_modules/@types` and `types` defined as type roots in `tsconfig`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es5",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "typeRoots" : ["./types", "./node_modules/@types"]
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: Works fine for me, did you forget a type somewhere? [playground example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=declare%20namespace%20angular%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20interface%20IFilterService%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20(name%3A%20'shortDate')%3A(date%3ADate)%20%3D%3E%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20const%20%24filter%3A%20angular.IFilterService%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20formatFn%3A(date%3ADate)%20%3D%3E%20string%20%3D%20%24filter('shortDate')%3B)

Comment: Can you add the code that declares the injected instance of $filter (e.g. parameter) you are using? One thing, though don't add your types folder to `"typeRoots"` you don't need to and it is misleading.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I updated the question to indicate how `$filter` is declared. Standalone it's fine, the issue seems to be the interplay with Angular's existing type declarations.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to reproduce